# Install BeautifulSoup using pip3 failed

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to add `BeatifulSoup` to my python project, but after typing `pip3 install BeautifulSoup`, it returns,

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Downloading BeatifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/27/cw_r5rjs6rg5vqnqmvbjs9n00000gn/T/pip-build-tddl0x3f/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    ---------------------------------------------


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/27/cw_r5rjs6rg5vqnqmvbjs9n00000gn/T/pip-build-tddl0x3f/BeautifulSoup
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I tried `pip3 install --upgrade pip3`, it returns,

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions)
No matching distribution found for pip3
```

I do know there is a collision with python2 and python3 when executing the setup.py file but I don't know how to solve this problem to run correctly so please help me.

Comment: The problem seems to be with BeautifulSoup's code, but for upgrading pip you should use `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`. BeautifulSoup got slightly renamed, and version 4 is the one that is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install bs4`? Works for me

Comment: Thanks you all! I've succeeded using `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip3 and `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` ;)

Comment: And I do need to install `bs4` to run the project, so thanks Noah ;)